# ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type -8 for column AAA$T

Tags: hive, sqoop

I have a view in oracle db, in the view one column is ROWID column,
Once I try to import the load into sqoop it throws following error:

```
.
.
.
    17/09/14 08:15:32 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
17/09/14 08:15:32 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: select * from user1.table1 where  (1 = 0) 
17/09/14 08:15:32 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: select * from user1.table1 where  (1 = 0) 
17/09/14 08:15:32 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: select * from user1.table1 where  (1 = 0) 
17/09/14 08:15:32 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: Cannot resolve SQL type -8
17/09/14 08:15:32 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: Cannot resolve SQL type -8
17/09/14 08:15:32 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: Cannot resolve SQL type -8
17/09/14 08:15:32 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: Cannot resolve SQL type -8
17/09/14 08:15:32 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type -8 for column AAA$col
17/09/14 08:15:32 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type -8 for column AAA$col
17/09/14 08:15:32 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type -8 for column AAA$col
17/09/14 08:15:32 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type -8 for column AAA$col
17/09/14 08:15:32 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type -8 for column AAA$col
17/09/14 08:15:32 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type -8 for column AAA$col
17/09/14 08:15:32 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type -8 for column AAA$col
17/09/14 08:15:32 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type -8 for column AAA$col
17/09/14 08:15:32 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type -8 for column AAA$col
17/09/14 08:15:32 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type -8 for column AAA$col
17/09/14 08:15:32 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type -8 for column AAA$col
17/09/14 08:15:32 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.parseNullVal(ClassWriter.java:1389)
.
.
.
```

The command I am using to import the data:

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.20.50.111:1521/abc" \
--username user1 \
--password "passes" \
--query 'select * from user1.table1 where $CONDITIONS' \
--hive-import \
--create-hive-table \
--hive-table sv.table1 \
--map-column-hive 'AAA$col'=STRING \
--target-dir "/home/table1" \
--m 1
```

I understand that ROWID can not be imported directly, so I am using --map-column-hive option.
What else I can try ?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java mapping is also required to create POJO.

Add `--map-column-java 'AAA$col'=String`

Comment: it worked and it loaded the data in hdfs, but hive could not create the table and it failed with another error.

Comment: ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: Hive does not support the SQL type for column AAA$col

Comment: I can create another external table in hive on top of the dumped data, but still is there any other way to create the hive table with --hive -table option for the same issue ?

Comment: Actually I replaced the --map-column-hive option with --map-column-java but after adding --map-column-java it worked,

Comment: @Arvind yes need to add both of them. You can accept the answer to close it.